# Crear método en BaseRespository

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework enfoque code first. Tengo un método que se repite en varios de mi respositorios el cual es este:

```
public IEnumerable<MarcaExtend> SelectList(Expression<Func<Marca, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (PosContext Context = new PosContext())
        {
            var result = Context.Marcas
                .Where(predicate)
                .Select(x => new MarcaExtend
                {
                    MarcaExtendId = x.MarcaId,
                    Descripcion = x.Descripcion
                }).ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Como generalmente traigo codigo/valor he creado una clase que me sirva para todas las entidades.

```
public class UniversalExtend
{
    public int UniversalExtendId { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Y quiero hacer este método que me sirva para todos los casos donde recupere codigo valor.

```
public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> SelectList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (PosContext Context = new PosContext())
        {

            var result = Context.Set<T>()
                .Where(predicate)
                .Select(x => new UniversalExtend
                {
                    UniversalExtendId = x.  Obtener de la entidad
                    Descripcion       = x.  Obtener de la entidad
                })
        }
    }
```

El problema es obtener el Id de cada entidad en todas mis clases le Id es el nombre de la clase + Id = NombreClaseId => ModeloId, ProveedorId, ClienteId, etc.
Y también todas tienen un campo Descripcion.
Sería posible de usar reflection para recuperar el nombre de la entidad y agregarle la palabra Id y recorrer toda la clase encontrar la propiedad Descripcion y ponerla donde lo necesito, sería posible? hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?
Leandro me da este error
[image: Error]

No esta trayendo nada muestro la query eb la db

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[MarcaId] AS [MarcaId], 
[Extent1].[Descripcion] AS [Descripcion]
FROM [dbo].[Marcas] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Descripcion] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'W'
```

Comment: estas realizando el ToList() dentro del SelectList2() que defines dentro del _sdMarca. Edite el ejemplo del codigo

Comment: Tienes razón eso me faltaba, pero la consulta no esta trayendo nada te deje la consulta que vi en el prifiler

Comment: quizas no devuelve es el linq porque quizas el filtro no retorna nada, que pasa si quitas el Where(). Valida tambien el automap este conviertiendo correctamente?

Comment: Es que necesito un constains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi como defines un `predicate` podrias defini un parametro de `source`, de esta forma indicar que campos debes mapear

```
public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> SelectList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, UniversalExtend>> source)
{
    using (PosContext Context = new PosContext())
    {

        var result = Context.Set<T>()
            .Where(predicate)
            .Select(source).ToList();
    }
}
```

y lo usarias

```
var result = modeloRepo.SelectList(x=> x.Prop1 == valor , x => new UniversalExtend()
                                                    {
                                                        UniversalExtendId = x.ModeloId,
                                                        Descripcion = x.Descripcion
                                                    });
```

Comment: Leandro, donde  me indicas "lo usarías" esa parte de código va dentro del método SelectList?

Comment: no dentro no, es el parametro source que se agrega al SelectList(), veras que es la forma en como invocarias el metodo

Comment: Leandro me da este error The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: la verdad no sabria decirte porque ese mensajes, por lo general se da cuando tienes una propiedad que se carga por lazy load y la quieres acceder fuera del using que define el contexto de EF

Comment: 'listDGV = _repositoryMarca.SelectList2(x => x.Descripcion.Contains(marca.Descripcion),
                        x => new UniversalExtend()
                        {
                            UniversalExtendId = x.MarcaId,
                            Descripcion = x.Descripcion
                        });' Quedo así, funciono excelente

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es crear una interfaz, pongamosle de nombre `IUniversalExtendable` con las propiedades que deseas recuperar de la entidad, por ejemplo:

```
public interface IUniversalExtendable
{
    int UniversalExtendId { get; }
    string Descripcion { get; } 
}
```

luego las entidades concretas podrían implementar esta interfaz:

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Modelo : IUniversalExtendable
{
    public int ModeloId { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    // Agregamos esta propiedad para cumpir con la interfaz
    public int UniversalExtendId => ModeloId; // C# 6
    //public int UniversalExtendId { get { return ModeloId: } } // C# 5

    ...
}
```

Y luego simplemente ya podrías utilizar un constrain: `where T : IUniversalExtendable` para no utilizar reflection

```
public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> SelectList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    where T : IUniversalExtendable
{
    using (PosContext Context = new PosContext())
    {
        var result = Context.Set<T>()
            .Where(predicate)
            .Select(x => new UniversalExtend
            {
                // Como T es IUniversalExtendable posee estas dos propiedades
                UniversalExtendId = x.UniversalExtendId,
                Descripcion       = x.Descripcion
            })

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, gracias por responder, Modelo al heredar de UniversalExtendable se implementan las dos propiedades que tiene, pero todas mis clases ya tienen la propiedad Desripcion

Comment: De todas maneras debes de colocarlo en la interfaz, de otro modo no podrás acceder a ella en el momento de hacer el select ya que al colocar el constrain estas limitando a que `T` implemente la interfaz y si `Descipcion` no es parte de la interfaz entonces `Descripcion = x.Descipcion` será error de sintaxis ya que x que es de tipo `IUniversalExtendable` no contiene ninguna propiedad llamadad `Descripcion`

Comment: Estimado Carlos, muy buena tu respuesta gracias a ti veo que hay varias maneras de hacer lo que quería conseguir, lastima que no se pueden marcar las dos respuestas.